# Outlook 2010: Set individual properties of all folders to "Do not archive items in this folder"

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

Is there any way to set the AutoArchive properties of all Outlook 2010 folders with one command?

I imported the folders from Outlook 2007 and some folders are set to not archive while others are set to use the default AutoArchive settings.

I'd like a fresh start (a reset) of the folder property settings so that I can turn AutoArchive on and then choose the folders I want to be archived.

I've searched this site and the web in general, but no luck, maybe I'm using the wrong keywords?